# Exported Object is distorted from what Blender previews

Tags: export

I just recently started getting into 3D modeling to design objects for Flight Simulators. I'm currently working on modeling the United Logo for the hangers. I built it in Blender by "CRTL + Right Clicking" on a reference image, and then extruding the face plates. But, when I go to open the .stl or .obj in a 3D viewer the shape is completely messed up, parts are missing, etc.

Here is what I see in Blender:
[image]

Here is what I see outside of Blender:
[image]
[image]

Why is this happening? What am I missing?

Thanks,
Brady

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well, not all 3D viewers are good, and we don't know which one you are using. Make sure the STL look right in Blender to be sure if the issue is from the export or not. If it's good, then maybe check your game or viewer's documentation to see if there's something specific in their mesh features support. If it isn't, then check you mesh in Blender, remove doubles, apply transforms, check normals, and check your export settings.

Comment: In the pictures, I was using TinkerCAD but the same result occurred in the 3D Viewer stock with Windows. The interesting thing is that when I exported the file to what Microsoft Flight Simulator reads, .glft, everything but some lighting was correct. I ended just converting the United Logo to an SVG file then converting to mesh in Blender which has a clean export no matter the viewer or the format. Thanks anyway!